# Android convert listview data into pdf file and save

Tags: android, listview, pdf

I have a custom listview and I want to make pdf from the whole listview. I refered many posts  But did not find whow to convert whole listitems into pdf.
I am trying this and its showing errors:

```
pdf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                        if (!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {

                        }
                        File pdfDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "MyProject");
                        if (!pdfDir.exists()){
                            pdfDir.mkdir();
                        }

                        File pdfFile = new File(pdfDir, "myPdfFile_new.pdf");

                        try {
                            createPdf();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

and this is my createpdf()

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void createPdf() throws IOException {

        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
        PdfDocument.Page page = null;
        // crate a page description

        for (int i = 0; i < bitmaps.size(); i++) {
            Bitmap bitmap = bitmaps.get(i);
            PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(1400, 1979, i).create();

            // start a page
            page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
            if (page == null) {
                return;
            }
            Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
            document.finishPage(page);
        }

        // finish the page


        // write the document content
        fileHandler = new FileHandler();
        File pdf = fileHandler.getNewFileToWrite(AppConstants.FileExtensions.PDF); //crete and get file

        try {
            document.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(pdf));
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

        // close the document
        document.close();

    }
```

[image]

My listview contains large number of items in it, so how can i convert the whole listview to pdf. All your suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Show error logs. Simply iterate over the arraylist which contains your data and create pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say iterate through data that you want to write into the file and then copy the same data to PDF file while creating PDF file.

Comment: hmmm let me try this.